# Background slideshow (javascript) fade transition effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, fade

I am trying to apply the fade effect to the javascsript background slideshow. When I changed the value, JS ignored it. I tried fadeIn and fadeOut. What is wrong with this code?

```
var bgimages=new Array()
bgimages[0]="tenis.jpg"
bgimages[1]="rtrr.jpg"
bgimages[2]="tenis.jpg"

//preload images
var pathToImg=new Array()
for (i=0;i<bgimages.length;i++) {
    pathToImg[i]=new Image()
    pathToImg[i].src=bgimages[i]
}
var inc=-1

function bgSlide() {
    if (inc<bgimages.length-1)
        inc++
    else
        inc=0

    document.body.background=pathToImg[inc].src
}

if (document.all||document.getElementById)
    window.onload=new Function('bgSlide(); setInterval("bgSlide()",3000),fade(2000)')
```

Comment: You can find live examples for what you are trying to achieve on this webpage: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Comment: Thanks but it is not answer to my question. I want to use javascript, no css3. Css3 have bad browsers support.

Comment: @user2097021 thanks for the green check! Hate to bother you, but you can vote up my answer too, as long as you have 15 or more pts. For correct protocol see this link: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not fade background images. You can fade images in `<img>` tags.

Here is my jsFiddle [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/totallytotallyamazing/p6ac5u27/).

Here is some sample code (including JQuery, CSS, and HTML):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
img{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    display:none;
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function fader() {
    $("img").first().appendTo('#wrap').fadeOut(3000);
    $("img").first().fadeIn(3000);    
    setTimeout(fader, 4200);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="fader();">
<div id="wrap">
<img src="http://stats.hashweb.org/static/img/jsfiddle-logo.png">
<img src="http://startbootstrap.com/templates/freelancer/img/profile.png">
<img src="http://www.silvercoinstoday.com//images/Silver-Element-Atomic-Structure.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that "you can not fade background images", you can fade-in and fade-out the DIVs whose background URLs are the images you want to fade.

The demo above from totallytotallyamazing, however, does not give the desired result where images should dissolve from one to the other, and not leave a blank screen in between.